# Swapping a token for SOL on Jupiter. An example from github

Tags: spl-token, rust, swap, jupiter, dex

I've found this repository https://github.com/jup-ag/sol-swap-flash-fill

It claims that it can swap **ANY** SPL token for SOL. After having examined the code, though, I haven't found any place in it where a token address would be specified.

How does it work then? Is it really capable of swapping **ANY** token that I'll send to it provided that I've deployed the program?

P.S. Assume that there's enough of liquidity on Jupiter of a selected token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program appears to be a flash loan program, so the idea is you can borrow the SOL at the start of the transaction to do any trade in the middle, as long as you repay that SOL later in the transaction.

This means that it works with any protocol, and the mints must be included in some instructions in the middle of the transaction.

Comment: where's the token address specified in it then?

Comment: In the *other* instructions in your transaction

Comment: Which? Will you show me an example?

Comment: Sure, Raydium, Jupiter, Orca, Phoenix, Openbook -- any of the trading protocols on Solana

Comment: Once again: **WHERE** is the address of a token that's exchanged is specified? In regards to the code on github I've pointed to. Will show me an example of it? The code.

Comment: I other word: when I entend to send a TX using that code, how or where will I specify a token address that I want to exchange for SOL?

Comment: There's an example showing how to specify a token type to trade with Jupiter at https://github.com/jup-ag/sol-swap-flash-fill/blob/f6ad68569fc0ba77da6193601b4ac2af7ae9437a/cli/flash-fill.ts#L110

Comment: That's it. Thanks.